# How to clear database session data if they are considered to be old?

Tags: php

I want to clear database session data when their creation column data is too high. How to make that successfully happen ?

---

**EDIT :**

Some code :

```
// starting a session
public static function getIstance($_MYSESSION_CONF)
    {
        if (!isset(self::$instance)) {
            $c = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $c;
            self::$instance->setUp($_MYSESSION_CONF);
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

private function setUp($config) {

        $this->db_type = $config["DATABASE_TYPE"];
        $this->db_name = $config["DB_DATABASE"];
        $this->db_pass = $config["DB_PASSWORD"];
        $this->db_server = $config["DB_SERVER"];
        $this->db_username = $config["DB_USERNAME"];

        $this->table_name_session = $config["TB_NAME_SESSION"];
        $this->table_name_variable = $config["TB_NAME_VALUE"];
        $this->table_column_sid = $config["SID"];
        $this->table_column_name = $config["NAME"];
        $this->table_column_value = $config["VALUE"];
        $this->table_column_fexp = $config["FEXP"];
        $this->table_column_ua = $config["UA"];
        $this->table_column_exp = $config["EXP"];

        $this->sid_name = $config["SESSION_VAR_NAME"];
        $this->overwrite = ($config["OVERWRITE_PHP_FUNCTION"]=='1')?true:false;
        $this->sid_len = intval($config["SID_LEN"]);
        $this->session_duration = intval($config["DURATION"]);
        $this->session_max_duration = intval($config["MAX_DURATION"]);
        $this->use_cookie = ($config["USE_COOKIE"]=='1')?true:false;
        $this->encrypt_data = ($config["CRIPT"]=='1')?true:false;
        $this->encrypt_key = $config["CRIPT_KEY"];

        $this->hijackBlock = ($config["ENABLE_ANTI_HIJACKING"]=='1')?true:false;
        $this->hijackSalt = $config["ANTI_HIJACKING_SALT"];

        $this->dbConnection();
        $this->readSessionId();
        //check if i have to overwrite php
        if ($this->overwrite) { // it's true
            //yes.. i'm the best so i overwrite php function
            //Make sure session cookies expire when we want it to expires
            ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', $this->session_duration);            
            //set the value of the garbage collector
            ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', $this->session_max_duration);
            // set the session name to our fantastic name
            ini_set('session.name', $this->sid_name);                        

            // register the new handler
            session_set_save_handler(
                array(&$this, 'open'),
                array(&$this, 'close'),
                array(&$this, 'read'),
                array(&$this, 'write'),
                array(&$this, 'destroy'),
                array(&$this, 'gc')
            );

//          register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');

            // start the session and cross finger
            session_id($this->getSessionId());
            session_start();
        }
    }
    ...
    function gc($maxlifetime)
    {
        $diff = time() - $this->session_max_duration;
        $this->SQLStatement_DeleteExpiredSession->bindParam(':time', $diff, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        if ($this->SQLStatement_DeleteExpiredSession->execute()===FALSE) {
            //trigger_error("Somenthing goes wrong with the garbace collector", E_USER_ERROR);
            trigger_error("Somenthing goes wrong with the garbace collector");
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the timestamp for every update on table .

get the life time of session through  `$lifetime = ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');`

Delete the rows from db which is more than `updatedtimestamp + $lifetime`

Comment: well, if you use default php session storage (file system), you don't need to worry, it will take care of garbage collection automatically. But if you want to implement database storage for session follow my above answer.

Comment: it's difficult to implement ! there are already the gc and delete function sin my class file !

Comment: I cannot say without seeing your code! show me some code to help you. btw, without storing time stamp how would you decide which is older & still user is live?